# Solr terms component over multiple fields?

Tags: search, autocomplete, lucene, solr

I am able to receive the most frequently used terms in my index via the terms compontent described here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent

However this only seems to work for exactly one field. 
I would really like to have this functionality over several fields.

I am aware that I can use an extra field that I fill with all the data when indexing, but I would like to leverage this redundancy if possible.

Is there a possibility to use the termscomponent over several fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to use the termscomponent over several fields?

No, the current implementation of TermsComponent takes only a single field, as noted in the documentation.

Perhaps it would be interesting to implement this, accepting multiple comma-separated fields in `terms.fl`, then setting per-field parameters as with faceting, e.g. `terms.<field>.limit`

I'm not familiar enough with the implementation to say if this is possible or really desirable, I'd try asking about it on the [solr-dev list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-dev/).

If this is about implementing suggestions / autocomplete, take a look at the [Suggester component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra terms.fl=fieldName parameters.
Just like for the facet.field parameter.

I hope this helps